# Undefined index PHP while parsing JSON

Tags: php, json, string

I am having a strange issue with Undefined index in my PHP code.

```
foreach ($arr as $event) {
        $place = "";
        $place = "Location: ".$event['locations']['title'];
}
```

And I am getting that error: **Undefined index: locations in...**

**['locations']['title']** is coming from the JSON I am parsing.

I know that there are some reserved words like **$this**, etc. But don't think **locations** is one of these words.

I have tried also declaring the locations like this

```
$locations = "";
```

But still see the error in the logs.

**JSON**

```
  [ {  
      "title":"8 Grand Pianos Concert (16 November 2019)",
      "timeFrom":"2019-11-16 19:00:00",
      "timeTo":"2019-11-16 22:00:00",
      "listText":"Concerts in.....",
      "url":"https://concert-16-november-2019",
      "imageUrl":"https://8108273152422838272_o.jpg?f=62051",
         "locations":{  
         "title":"Complex",
         "url":"https://locations/complex"
      }
   }
]
```

This is the link to the source
https://plovdiv2019.eu/en/feed/events/json

Comment: show the json itself, as well as the code where you parse it.

Comment: What is the var_dump of $event?

Comment: Added JSON and link to the JSON Source

Comment: Not all of the results have a locations object, so check to make sure it exists before you try to access it.

Comment: Ahh, I haven't thought of that. Thanks @aynber